# How To Disable AFNetworking Cache

Tags: ios, caching, afnetworking

Is it possible to disable all the cache features from AFNetworking?

I am building my own custom cache system and don't want this to take up disk space too.

Thanks,
Ashley

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Cacheing is handled application-wide by `NSURLCache`. If you don't set a shared cache, requests are not cached. Even with a shared `NSURLCache`, the default implementation on iOS does not support disk cacheing anyway.

That said, unless you have a very particular reason to write your own cacheing system, I would **strongly** recommend against it. `NSURLCache` is good enough for 99.9% of applications: it handles cache directives from incoming responses and uses them appropriately with new requests, and does so automatically in a way that is unlikely to be a performance bottleneck in your application. As someone who has wasted untold hours making one myself (*and later throwing it away since it was completely unnecessary*), I'd say that there are much better places to focus your development attention.

Comment: is there any way to disable it still? I really need this as my cache system is a bit unorthodox anyway. It's a real must have to disable the cache.

Comment: It's off by default. You have to opt-in by creating an `NSURLCache` and setting that as the shared cache.

Comment: Is it already? Currently it looks like it will be autogenerated for you. https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/experimental-1.0RC1/AFNetworking/UIImageView%2BAFNetworking.m#L70

Comment: I assumed that `AFImageCache` wasn't really what OP meant by cacheing. If that is the case though, the solution would be not to use the `UIImageView` category, I guess.

Comment: I cover this in the following blog post - thanks! http://blog.originate.com/blog/2014/02/20/afimagecache-vs-nsurlcache/

Comment: @mattt do you have any ideas on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28755444/ios-app-getting-stale-data-from-rest-api-until-browser-hits-same-api) mattt? I'm using AFNetworking which has worked amazingly so far and I'm not sure if my issue is related to your library or not. I have cachePolicy set to ignore local and remote cache.

Answer (score 25):

Initially I found Jason Moore's answer to work, however recently I have noticed my app is still caching requests. I am not using the latest AFNetworking, so I do not know if caching has been addressed in more recent builds.

Apple's URLCache Project has this to say:

> By default, the Cocoa URL loading system uses a small shared memory
>   cache. We don't need this cache, so we set it to zero when the
>   application launches.

And then does this to disable the cache.

```
NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:0
                                                        diskCapacity:0
                                                            diskPath:nil];
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];
[sharedCache release];
```

This will disable all caching for your whole app, which may not be ideal in some situations, but as `NSURLRequest` is not honouring the requested cache policy, it is the only option left that I can see.

Comment: worked for me even with AFnetworking - caches were corrupting resumed download from https service ...

Answer (score 23):

I've found on iOS 6 that requests are sometimes cached, even if the request has `NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData`. Adding a cache response block that returns `nil` prevents the request from being cached.

```
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url
                                              cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData
                                          timeoutInterval:20];
AFJSONRequestOperation *op =
[AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request];

// DISABLE CACHE //
[op setCacheResponseBlock:^NSCachedURLResponse *(NSURLConnection *connection, NSCachedURLResponse *cachedResponse) {
    return nil;
}];

[op start];
```

Comment: For using the `AFHTTPClient`, we should override `requestWithMethod:path:parameters` .Call super method to get the `NSURLRequest` and say `request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData;`

Comment: Could you please fix the wrong type of enum in your code snippet? It's gonna be miss leading for anyone who doesn't notice there are two updates.

Comment: Setting the cache policy to NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed is incorrect. You are using a NSURLCacheStoragePolicy value instead of a NSURLRequestCachePolicy. What effectively happens is that you set it to NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad which has the same value (2) as NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed.

Comment: I just updated the answer to remove the incorrect enum. Sorry for the confusion - clearly editing the answer is better than adding updates!

Comment: According to the NSURLRequest headers, NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData is unimplemented, so I wouldn't rely on it. You may want to use NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData instead.

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately non of these methods worked for me. The only way I've managed to get the cache disabled is this way:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager.requestSerializer setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
```

[Here's the original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23604799/923642)

Comment: I have a singleton to manage Backend calls. I put these two lines of code in my init method and all work well!

Answer (score 0):

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:10];
```

Answer (score 0):

This may depend on your server implementation, but adding `Cache-Control:no-store` header to your outgoing request should result in a response that contains the same header, thus commanding `NSURLCache` to not cache the response to disk.

IMHO this is a better approach than disabling disk-caching completely, especially if you're writing SDK code that will be used by other applications which may want to utilize `NSURLCache`.