# AFNetworking disable caching

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I'm trying to get a JSON file from a server then display it in a table, this works fine, however, for some reason AFNetworking is caching the JSON file even after a app restart.
How can I disable this?

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://?json"];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation
                                         JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                         success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id responseObject)
                                         {

                                             self.dataget = [responseObject objectForKey:@"data"];
                                             [self.tableView reloadData];


                                         }
                                         failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id responseObject)
                                         {

                                             [HUD hideUIBlockingIndicator];
                                         }];

    [operation start];
```

The json file is probably not cached server side:
`Cache-Control: no-cache[CRLF]`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How To Disable AFNetworking Cache](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968050/how-to-disable-afnetworking-cache)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cache behavior can be set on `NSMutableURLRequest` objects, with `setCachePolicy:`. Otherwise, the built-in shared `NSURLCache` will respect the caching behavior defined by the server (which I would recommend tuning and taking advantage of, rather than outright disregarding).

Comment: Stupid me, I did set an NSURLCache following a tutorial to `NSURLCache *URLCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:4 * 1024 * 1024 
                                                       diskCapacity:20 * 1024 * 1024 
                                                           diskPath:nil];
  [NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:URLCache];` Removed that from the AppDelegate and works fine now.

Comment: I cover this info & more in the following blog post : http://blog.originate.com/blog/2014/02/20/afimagecache-vs-nsurlcache/

Answer (score 0):

AFNetworking doesn't do any caching.  Also, the "Cache-Control" HTTP header tells the *client* not to cache the page (ie. AFNetworking), not the server.

It sounds like your server is caching the JSON page.

Comment: But, if this is the case, why does my browser show the most recent version of the JSON and the app doesn't?

Comment: Hmm, interesting.  AFNetworking uses the built-in NSURLCache, so I was wrong on that.  What do you get if you visit the page via the browser on the iOS device/simulator?  Is the device configured to access the server in the same way as the browser (ie. no proxies in between)?

Answer (score 0):

AFNetworking doesn't cache anything. You should probably check the cache control headers of the response. If i am not wrong then your server is sending some cache control headers which NSUrlConnection is taking into consideration. I would recommend you to set the caching policy of NSURLRequest to NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData before making request to server