# AFNetworking - do not cache response

Tags: ios, json, caching, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I'm using this code to pull a simple JSON feed from a server:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

[manager GET:kDataUrl parameters:nil
 success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
     NSLog(@"response: %@", responseObject);
 }
 failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
     NSLog(@"JSON DataError: %@", error);
 }];
```

It works. However, after I change the JSON file at `kDataUrl`, and verify that the change is made in a browser, when I run the app again, I still get the previous response.

It seems that AFNetworking is somehow caching the old response. I do not want this behavior. I want to download the current feed. Is there some kind of setting or parameter I need to set to turn off caching?

Comment: did you solve this? I can't find something to set cache policy in AFHTTPRequestOperationManager

Comment: I cover caching in AFNetworking in this blog post - AFImageCache & NSURLCache. Maybe you will find it use flu : http://blog.originate.com/blog/2014/02/20/afimagecache-vs-nsurlcache/

Comment: try like this: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33767908/volunteermatch-api-objective-c/33886449#33886449

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Make long story short, just define your AFNetworking manager:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager.requestSerializer setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
```

Enjoy!

Comment: There is no such method named setCachePolicy for AFNetworking. Could you please make it more clear?

Comment: With the new AFNetworking library versions you can set this to url session configuration object. `NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    configuration.requestCachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData;`

Answer (score 12):

What you are experiencing is the effect of the URL cache (see [NSURLCache](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLCache_Class/Reference/Reference.html)).

The caching behavior of the request can be defined by setting a "Cache Policy" for the `NSMutableURLRequest` object, e.g.:

```
NSMutableURLRequest* request = ...;
[request setCachePolicy: myCachePolicy];
```

The default caching behavior (`NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy`) is appropriate for the current protocol, which is HTTP. And for the HTTP protocol, a GET requests will be cached by default!

And, AFNetworking does not change the default behavior of the request!

Now, you could set another cache policy, for example:

`NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData`

> Specifies that the data for the URL load should be loaded from the originating source. No existing cache data should be used to satisfy a URL load request.

This is likely the desired behavior you want to achieve:

```
[request setCachePolicy: NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
```

The problem here is, that the super "convenient" API does not provide a way to configure the URL cache behavior of the request. You cannot access the used request at all.

Thus, I would suggest to use a lower level API where you have control about the created `NSMutableURLRequest` object, and set the cache policy accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

```
manager.requestSerializer.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicyReturnCacheDataElseLoad
```

Answer (score 1):

For Swift poeple

```
let manager = AFHTTPSessionManager()
manager.requestSerializer.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringCacheData
```

Answer (score 1):

With AFNetworking 3:

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
sessionConfiguration.requestCachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData;

AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL
                                                         sessionConfiguration:sessionConfiguration];
```

Answer (score 1):

try to add some rubbish at the end of your URL (for example, timestamp)

```
kDataUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?%f", kDataUrl, [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]];
```

In this case, you would request fresh data every time. 
That works for me))

Answer (score 1):

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"no-store" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Cache-Control"];
[manager.requestSerializer setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
```

Adding the `Cache-Control:no-store` header to the request, assuming your server is implemented correctly, will return a response with the same header thus disabling `NSURLCache` disk cache for any request that contains this header.

Answer (score 0):

I don't feel good about it, but here is what works. In the AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:0
                                                            diskCapacity:0
                                                                diskPath:nil];
    [NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];
```