# Calling to https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id is caching the json

Tags: ios, swift, app-store-connect, nsmutableurlrequest

I have a really strange problem making a request to https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=APPID

If I try this url in my browser it gives me the current version of the app. But if I call this from the iOS app it gives me the old one.

This is the code that I'm using

```
let stringUrl : String = "https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=APPID"

    let req : NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL(string: stringUrl)!, cachePolicy: NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData, timeoutInterval: 10.0)
    req.httpMethod = "get"

    let manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()
    manager.responseSerializer = AFJSONResponseSerializer()

    let r = manager.httpRequestOperation(with: req as URLRequest!,
        success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation?,responseObject: Any?) in
            if let responseDic :Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = responseObject as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {

                let currentVersion: String = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleShortVersionString") as! String

                let results = responseDic.first?.value as! Array<AnyObject>

                let dic =  results.first as! Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
                let version : String = dic["version"] as! String
                //let version : String = responseDic.object(forKey: "results")?[0].object(forKey: "version") as! String

                self.isUpToDate = currentVersion == version

                delegate.onVersionReceived(version)
            }
        },
        failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation?,error: Error?) in

    })
    r.start()
```

Any idea about what's happening?

Comment: You can see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25210143/5965126

Comment: could it be related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23604799/2305175?

Comment: Not working. This is something really weird, even with a new installation it is showing the older version.

Comment: Did you try a cachebuster argument in the url?

Comment: That worked but I don't know why the cachepolicy does not work. Do you know how long it takes to refresh the cache? The app is already in production

Comment: No, no, no! You need to do `let dic = responseDic["result"] as? [[String:AnyObject]]`

Comment: I think it was the cache. I have added a random parameter in the url and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

[Pablo Martinez wrote in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41840289/calling-to-https-itunes-apple-com-lookupid-is-caching-the-json/54880204#comment82845837_41840289):

> I think it was the cache. I have added a random parameter in the url and it solved my problem.

This solved the problem for me, too. Others should definitely try this first.

Comment: Actually adding a random parameter works pretty well.