# AFHTTPRequestOperationManager always uses the cached response

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, ios9, afnetworking-2

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager always give the cache response by default or otherwise.

Does anybody know How to solve the issue?

Comment: Check this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968050/how-to-disable-afnetworking-cache

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
[[[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager] requestSerializer] setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
```

Comment: Thanks @Satish Azad. I used this But it is not working at all. Giving the same old response.

Comment: First clear the cache memory before implementing this and the execute new implemented code.

Comment: what I am doing is. I am testing this webservice with two account. When I am using different accounts I'm supposed to get different responses. But this is not happening here.

Comment: AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;
    [manager.requestSerializer setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];

Comment: I think thats fine. Did you checked after clearing Local Cache data?

Comment: I even tried to forcefully ignore the cache using following lines.

Comment: NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:0
                                                            diskCapacity:0
                                                                diskPath:nil];
    [NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];

Answer (score 0):

Just try this.
      [manager.requestSerializer setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];

Comment: Thanks @孙博弘. I used this But it is not working at all. Giving the same old response.

Comment: How do you know the response is old response?Do you have use the Charles to see what happed?

Comment: Actually these are dummy accounts for testing. I know the response that is coming. The same is implemented for android and it is working fine. I am using AFHTTPRequestOperationManager but i am getting old response only after successful login.

Comment: Have you check the request body?Maybe you have the wrong request.

Comment: Yes checked. It is perfectly fine. If I remove the build and recompile it and test with different account then it works fine.